# fixed distance between a image tag and a paragraph tag

Tags: html, css

I am having an image and text to be displayed on a page. Is there any way to have fixed distance between the both? Tried with media queries but couldn't do it.

```html
<div id="element">
Text Here
<div class="imagehere">
    <img src="./img/pic.jpeg"/>
</div>
</div>
```

> Note: The text need to be displayed above the image. Problem is the text is disappearing when the image overlaps with it.

Comment: You can use margins or  flexbox if you want to display it like card ( use flex direction column and gap prop )

Comment: Will it be possible if text need to be displayed above the image. I will modify the question accordingly.

Comment: can you share you css which you are using !

Answer (score 1):

Add this style

```
.imagehere {
    margin-top: 10px; /* This will be fixed distance */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple margin will do the trick:

```css
.text-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <div class="text-wrapper">Text Here</div>
  <div class="imagehere">
    <img src="./img/pic.jpeg" />
  </div>
</div>
```